# My jQuery animation isnt working

Tags: jquery, facebook, html

I have a div that is partway off the screen and when u click a button it is supposed to move out. I posted my script here http://jsfiddle.net/53bSe/ it appears that it isn't working when I press the button. In jsfiddle it doesn't show it properly. It should look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC7bK.jpg and then the stuff on the right should animate out when the grey button is pressed.

My HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Facebook and Twitter Sliding Like and Follow</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
$('#test').click(function() {
  $('.facebook-sw').animate({
    left: '+=300'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
</script>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p id="test"></p>
        <div class="facebook-sw">
            <img class="fb-icon" src="image/fb-icon.PNG" width="110" height="113" alt="">
            <img class="fb-like-box" src="image/example.JPG" height="544" width="292" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    background-color:#636363;
}

.facebook-sw {
    margin-top:120px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:-300px;
}

.fb-icon {
    float:left;
    margin-right:14px;
}

.fb-like-box {
    float:left;
}

#test {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:50px;
    display:block;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this shows a JS error in your browser console?

Comment: So it doesnt animates it at all or is it doing it wrong?Coz I cant really see any thing happening in your jsFiddle.

Comment: The image should fly out of the window correct?

Comment: theres no animation going on at all and fly out of the window? the below answer is what it should look like its just im having issues

Comment: The problem is you are trying to apply left position in your element, which is static. Left position work on a non-static element(absolute, relative, fixed). So in css define position relative/absolute/fixed as per your situation. Also for better result or to define it by better way also define left initial value may be 0 in css also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.facebook-sw {
position: relative
}

.wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/53bSe/1/

Comment: its working in ur jsfiddle but not on my site why... here is a pastebin of my html/jquery http://pastebin.com/3XY2pu7L and here is a pastebin of my css http://pastebin.com/uW7iJ3Zw

Comment: I get errors if i do this    $(document).ready() {
 $('#test').click(function() {
   $('.facebook-sw').animate({
  left: '+=300'
   }, 5000, function() {
  // Animation complete.
   });
 });
});

Comment: now im getting an error in javascript console saying Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: weird, why dont you copy everything from here - http://fiddle.jshell.net/53bSe/2/show/